# jqGrid - custom sort function - sorting both numbers and text

Tags: jquery, excel, sorting, jqgrid

Using jqGrid 4.5.3 on a web page and I have data that can be either text or numeric.  I am using a custom sort function on the column, but it's not sorting the way I was expecting it to sort.

I have the following data in the rows in the grid, this is the order in which they are being sent:

```
123
654
321
Test
James
```

If I take that same data & put it in Excel and sort it, the order (from smallest to largest) is:

```
123
321
654
James
Test
```

If I sort it again in Excel, from largest to smallest, it is:

```
Test
James
654
321
123
```

In my jQgrid, the order always has the text first, then the numbers.  Both are ordered correctly (between themselves), but the text is always at the top of the grid.  The code for the custom sort is:

```
function myCustSort (myCell, rowObj ) {
    var n = myCell.length;
    var intRegex = /^\d+$/ ;
    var checkNumeric;
    checkNumeric = intRegex.test(myCell);
    if (typeof myCell === "string") {
        if ( checkNumeric === true) {
            return parseInt( myCell);
            }
        else {
            return myCell;
            }
        }
    else {
        return myCell;
        }
} // end myCustSort
```

The `colModel` for the column being sorted is:

```
{name:"TestData",
index:"TestData",
width:30,
align:"center", 
sorttype: function (cell, obj ) {
        return myCustSort (cell) ;
        },
xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>TestData"
},
```

I've had displays in the Custom Sort function, and it correctly evaluates the numerics as numeric and the strings as string, however, I cannot make it sort the same way the same data in Excel does.

I have looked at several examples of custom sort functions for jqGrid, but they are invoking a custom sort on grid data where it's sorting by a substring of that cell data.  I haven't been able to find one where the data being sorted is a mixture of numbers and text.

Please let me know if I'm missing something on the custom sort function for this column.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue I was having (the text always at the top, and other bizarre sort results).  Turns out there were several things happening at once, which I believe all contributed to the behavior of the sorting of data in the grid.

First issue was in the grid's `sortname`.  I had initially been sorting it by an ID number that in the course of changes I had changed to a hidden field.  I changed the stored procedure and the code to both sort the data from SQL by a date-time field that is displayed and is sortable on the grid.  This one change resolved the bizarre sorts that I had been getting, where the grid would have the same number - out of order - multiple times within the grid.

Second change was to the custom sort function.  My data would have one of three possible characteristics:

1. It could be a 3 digit number,
2. It could be a 4 digit number, or
3. It could be a string that would have a name or some text in it.

I could put displays in the function & see that it was calculating the length right & interpreting the characteristics of the data correctly.

I then re-wrote the Custom Sort function as follows:

```
function myCustSort (myCell, options, rowObj ) {
    var n = myCell.length;
    var intRegex = /^\d+$/ ;
    var checkNumeric;
    checkNumeric = intRegex.test(myCell);
    if (typeof myCell === "string") {
        var myIntStr;
        if ( checkNumeric === true) {
            if ( n === 3 ) {
                myIntStr = "0" + parseInt( myCell);
                }
            else {
                myIntStr = "0" + parseInt( myCell);
                myIntStr = myIntStr.substring(1);
                }
            }
        else {
            myIntStr = myCell;
            }
        return myIntStr;
        }
    else {
        return myCell;
        }
} // end myCustSort
```

So now, the text is sorted correctly, as are the numbers (so I don't have 10 & 1000 both before 2).  Thanks to @Oleg - whose posts on this subject I had read several times trying to debug what was wrong with my sort function.

Answer (score 0):

If your text value is having prefix and you have number , the below custom function will help.

```
function myCustSort(myCell, options, rowObj) {
var n = myCell.length;
var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
var checkNumeric;
checkNumeric = intRegex.test(myCell);
if (typeof myCell === "string") {
    var myIntStr;
    if (checkNumeric === true) {

        if (n === 9) {
            myIntStr = "0" + parseInt(myCell);
        }
        else if (n === 8) {
            myIntStr = "00" + parseInt(myCell);
        }
        else if (n === 7) {
            myIntStr = "000" + parseInt(myCell);
        }
        else if (n === 6) {
            myIntStr = "0000" + parseInt(myCell);
        }
        else if (n === 5) {
            myIntStr = "00000" + parseInt(myCell);
        }
        else if (n === 4) {
            myIntStr = "000000" + parseInt(myCell);
        }
        else if (n === 3) {
            myIntStr = "0000000" + parseInt(myCell);
        }
        else if (n === 2) {
            myIntStr = "00000000" + parseInt(myCell);
        }
        else {
            myIntStr = "000000000" + parseInt(myCell);
        }
    }
    else {

        var isChecktype = myCell.indexOf("PREFIX");
        if (isChecktype <= -1)  {
            var odvalue = myCell.split('PREFIX');
            var odlength = odvalue[1].length;

            if (odlength === 3) {
                myIntStr = "PREFIX" + "0" + parseInt(odvalue[1]);
            }
            else if (odlength === 2) {
                myIntStr = "PREFIX" + "00" + parseInt(odvalue[1]);
            }
            else {
                myIntStr = "PREFIX" + "000" + parseInt(odvalue[1]);
            }
        }


    }
    return myIntStr;
}
else {

    return myCell;
}
}
```